# Flutter: how to override the private state implementation of a Cupertino widget?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-sliver

I will first give a bit of background of my problem and then ask the actual question which I am trying to achieve:

**BACKGROUND:**

I posted this earlier question about preventing rows from disappearing as soon as they entered the padding area of the CupertinoScrollbar's parent Padding widget:

[Flutter Padding on CupertinoScrollbar - how to prevent row from disappearing as soon as they enter the padding area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73537544/flutter-padding-on-cupertinoscrollbar-how-to-prevent-row-from-disappearing-as/73537677)

I have figured out a workaround solution which involves removing the parent Padding widget entirely and instead wrapping the `SliverList` only in `SliverPadding` which achieves the padding on the list. However, this makes the scrollbar start at the top as it's the parent of the `SliverPadding` and thus doesn't know the padding for the inner `SliverList`.

I have figured out a solution for this problem. I can edit the source code of the `CupertinoScrollbar` and modify the following line in the `updateScrollbarPainter` method:

```
..padding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding
```

to what I need.

**QUESTION:**

This `updateScrollbarPainter` is part of the private state implementation `_CupertinoScrollbarState`, so I can't access it outside from my app.

Is there a workaround for this?

If not, is the only possible solution to modify the padding there is to copy the entire source code from this file into my app and then modify it there? It seems a bit complicated for modifying a single line of code no?

Here's the line I can modify:

[image]

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the issue and what do you expect as output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping widget with `MediaQuery` and provide the padding while it depends on context.

```dart
body: MediaQuery(
    data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(52), //here modify the one you want
    ),
    child: Scrollbar(
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method ends up adding the padding to the CustomScrollView too as its a child of the Scrollbar. This is no different than wrapping the entire thing in Padding itself (something I can't do as I don't want padding on the scrollview). I only want to change the padding for the scrollbar.